# How do I achieve this smoky shadow effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, vignette

How do I get the following shadow effect pls? In my image, I tried to add shadows and increased the size of the shadows. No avail. :(

**I want to get the shadow/smoky effect that is present in the borders of the red and green portions.** I think I can somehow get the drop shadow effect of the Christmas trees. Even the green portion has a smoky shadow effect. Would love to reproduce the effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edge effect is called a **vignette**.

You can simply draw a **radial gradient on a layer**...

[image: gradient]

You could also use the Inner Glow layer style on a layer.

The tree shadow is simply a large Drop Shadow layer style.

Or for more complex methods, Google will turn up hundreds of tutorials. The first few Google results....

http://www.all-things-photography.com/create-a-vignette-effect.html

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/psdtuts/-create-a-nondestructive-vignette-effect-in-seconds/

http://voices.yahoo.com/create-vignette-effect-photoshop-376634.html

http://www.lifeclever.com/quick-and-dirty-vignettes-in-photoshop/

Comment: The 2nd link (tv.adobe.com) had a nice video on how to do it. How do I post the image that I worked on? :)